# How to access part of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which consists of numbers matched with a word.
I want to be able to access part of the dictionary based on what the user enters.

How do I make it so that if the user enters a number, e.g. "2", the program picks the item from the dictionary that matches "2" and prints it? or if the user enters "hydrogen" (a word in the dictionary) it needs to print its corresponding number ("1").

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your dictionary look like?

Comment: In the future it would be helpful to show us what you have tried to solve the problem

Comment: You can either use one of the below solutions or use [bidict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dictionary looks like this (since you said numbers to elements):

```
elements = {'2': 'Hydrogen', '8': 'Oxygen'}
```

You can have this piece of code:

```
user_input = '2'
for key,value in elements.items():
   if user_input == key:
      print value
   if user_input == value:
      print key
```

You can convert the loop to a method:

```
def search_dictionary(user_input, haystack):
    for key,value in haystack.items():
        if user_input == key:
            return value
        if user_input == value:
            return key
```

Then use it like this:

```
user_input = raw_input('Please enter your search item: ')
elements = {'2': 'Hydrogen', '8': 'Oxygen'}
result = search_dictionary(user_input, elements)
if result:
    print("The result of your search is {0}".format(result))
else:
    print("Your search for {0} returned no results".format(user_input))
```

Comment: Note that this runs in `O(N)` time.

Comment: I don't think this is really that important for the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create either two dicts one that maps elements to their atomic number and one that maps atomic number to elements. This will in run in `O(1)` time.

```
>>> ele2atm = {'hydrogen':'2', 'oxygen':'8', 'carbon':'7'}
>>> atm2ele = {k:v for v, k in ele2atm.items()}
def get_value(key):
    try:
        return ele2atm[key]
    except KeyError:
        return atm2ele[key]


>>> get_value('8')
'oxygen'
>>> get_value('carbon')
'7'
```

or use the [`bidict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict) package that allows one-to-one mapping between keys and values.

Example:

```
>>> husbands2wives = bidict({'john': 'jackie'})
>>> husbands2wives['john'] # the forward mapping is just like with dict
'jackie'
>>> husbands2wives[:'jackie'] # use slice for the inverse mapping
'john'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {
    1: "baz",
    2: "bar",
    ...
}

dict2 = {
    "hydrogen": 1,
    "helium": 2,
    ...
}

input_ = raw_input("pick something: ")
try:
    print dict1[int(input_)]
except ValueError:
    print dict1[dict2[input_]]
except KeyError:
    print "Your desired key does not exist!"
```